# Perl: Why is . not anymore part of @INC in Debian 9?

Tags: perl, debian

In installing Debian 9 I found out that `.` is not anymore part of `@INC`.

Perl (v5.24.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

```
Built under linux
Compiled at Jan 15 2017 23:35:20
@INC:
 /etc/perl
 /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.24
 /usr/share/perl5
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24
 /usr/share/perl/5.24
 /usr/local/lib/site_perl
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: You could never rely on `.` being the script's directory anyway. Workaround: `use FindBin qw( $RealBin ); use lib $RealBin;`

Answer (score 14):

Because `.` has been removed from `@INC` for core modules in 5.24.1. That's a security feature to prevent an exploit that [this blog post](http://blogs.perl.org/users/todd_rinaldo/2016/11/what-happened-to-dot-in-inc.html) talks about.

> In February, I opened a ticket with Perl 5 Porters to get them to accept a non-default option to remove . from @INC. Unfortunately, I was beaten to the punch and an exploit was disclosed to Perl 5 Security. TL;DR: There are now known insecurities about having . in @INC.

The change is documented in [perldelta](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perldelta.pod#Core-modules-and-tools-no-longer-search-%22.%22-for-optional-modules) for 5.24.1.

> This prevents an attacker injecting an optional module into a process run by another user where the current directory is writable by the attacker, e.g. the /tmp directory.

It will most likely [be removed completely in 5.26](http://blogs.perl.org/users/todd_rinaldo/2016/11/how-removing-from-inc-is-about-to-break-cpan.html). [Here's more discussion](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2017/01/msg242362.html) on the p5p mailing list, taken from [this blog post](http://blogs.perl.org/users/sawyer_x/2017/01/perl-5-porters-mailing-list-summary-january-16th-22nd.html).

[Here are (some of) the commits](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=INC&type=Commits) that make these changes.

The [Perl Pumpkin](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlhist.html#THE-KEEPERS-OF-THE-PUMPKIN) Sawyer X also explains this in [the talk *Perl 5.24, 5.26, and the Future of Perl 5* he gave at FOSDEM 2017](https://fosdem.org/2017/schedule/event/perl5_future/). [Here is the recording](https://fosdem.cu.be/2017/K.4.201/perl5_future.mp4) of the talk<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1) [all videos from the Perl room at FOSDEM 2017](http://video.fosdem.org/2017/K.4.201/)</sup>

Comment: So the best future solution for code with new perl is to add "use lib '.'" in my programm??

Comment: @chris If you need it, yes. A better solution is to put your stuff in a `lib` dir and use `use lib "lib"`

Comment: Is @INC set at compilation of perl itself??

Comment: @chris I don't know exactly. Some part of it I believe is. But the `PERL5LIB` env variable is part of it, the `-I` (captial i) command line arg is part of it, and all your `use lib` pragmata are also part of it. You should read the p5p posts and the blog posts I linked to learn more about it.

Comment: I'd go with `FindBin` to add local libraries, and that way you don't have to worry about wrong cwds.

Comment: I wonder why they didn't simply make paths in `@INC` relative to the script rather than CWD. That would address the problem (and mean we could finally use `use lib '.';` instead of `use FindBin qw( $RealBin ); use lib $RealBin;`), but maybe it would break too much?

Comment: Also see the Debian bug report: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=588017